# javascript/D3 quirk?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var t =  g.on("click", function(d) {
      return data_series_1[d.iata]["EV"];
      });

   // So data_series_1 is an array of arrays.
   // d.iata = "BOS"
   // data_series_1[d.iata]["EV"] or
   // data_series_1["BOS"]["EV"] = "68"
```

However for some reason t is defined to be an array of length 80 or array[80] with each element being 0: g, 1: g, and so on...

Can someone explain what is going on and why I am not able to get a mapping of t = 68?

Comment: oh dumb - it's because of the g.on

Comment: How do I assign a variable outside the function though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var t;
g.on("click", function(d) {
    t = data_series_1[d.iata]["EV"];
});
```